# how to connect hdfs ha for elasticsearch snapshot?

Tags: elasticsearch, hadoop

I want to automatic connect to hdfs ha when namenode switch active to standby, which uri should be ?

```
PUT _snapshot/my_hdfs_repository
{
  "type": "hdfs",
  "settings": {
    "uri": "hdfs://namenode:8020/",
    "path": "/user/elasticsearch/repositories"
  }
}
```

till now, I manual change the uri when hdfs namenode switch

Comment: Isn't HDFS configuration which you need to change?

Comment: @Gibbs I already config hdfs ha with CDH

Comment: You'd need to use hdfs **`nameservice`** URL I think.

Comment: @mazaneicha thank you for your reply,
my nameservice is `nameservice1`, i config the following in /etc/hosts, but can not effect
```
ip1    nameservice1
ip2    nameservice1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my setting with ha hdfs and kerberos enabled.

```
PUT /_snapshot/elastic_hdfs_repository
{
    "type" : "hdfs",
    "settings" : {
      "dfs" : {
        "http" : {
          "policy" : "HTTPS_ONLY"
        }
      },
      "path" : "/elasticsearch/repositories/elastic_hdfs_repository",
      "conf" : {
        "dfs" : {
          "client" : {
            "failover" : {
              "proxy" : {
                "provider" : {
                  "my-cluster-nameservice" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "ha" : {
            "automatic-failover" : {
              "enabled" : {
                "my-cluster-nameservice" : "true"
              }
            },
            "namenodes" : {
              "my-cluster-nameservice" : "namenode1,namenode2"
            }
          },
          "data" : {
            "transfer" : {
              "protection" : "privacy"
            }
          },
          "namenode" : {
            "rpc-address" : {
              "my-cluster-nameservice" : {
                "namenode1" : "nn1.domain.com:8020",
                "namenode2" : "nn2.domain.com:8020"
              }
            }
          },
          "nameservices" : "my-cluster-nameservice"
        },
        "fs" : {
          "defaultFS" : "hdfs://elastic_hdfs_repository",
          "hdfs" : {
            "impl" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem"
          }
        },
        "hadoop.http.authentication.token.validity": 36000
      },
      "security" : {
        "principal" : "elasticsearch/_HOST@DOMAIN.COM"
      },
      "uri" : "hdfs://my-cluster-nameservice"
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)